# What's the design purpose of Gradle doFirst and doLast?

Tags: gradle

For example I have the Gradle script like:

```
myTask_A {
    doFirst {
        println "first string"

    }
    doLast {
        println "last string"
    }
}
```

The following two tasks have exactly the same execution result:

```
myTask_B {
    doFirst {
        println "first string"
        println "last string"
    }
}

myTask_C {
    doLast {
        println "first string"
        println "last string"
    }
}
```

What's the design purpose of the the doFirst & doLast as any of above tasks produces the same result?

Comment: check this - https://discuss.gradle.org/t/what-is-dolast-for/27731

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It has to do with extensibility, reuse and avoiding duplication.

For one built in tasks can be extended like:

```
task CopyAndThen(type: Copy) {
   doFirst {
      println "this is before the actual copy"
   }
   doLast {
      println "this is after the actual copy"
   }
}
```

The second common scenario that comes to mind is with [multi project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html), where you can have a task definition at the top of the project with common behavior:

```
allprojects {
    task myTask_a {
        doFirst {...}
    }
}
```

And then the specific projects can extend that.
The task essentially has a list of the [Closures](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html) that needs to be run and the choice of `doFirst` or `doLast` controls to which end of the list the insert goes to.

Comment: What if you declare multiple doFirsts or doLasts in a task?

Comment: it's a valid configuration, each `doFist` or `doLast` is a closure that gets added to the list, and they are executed in order.  Multiple `doLast` will be executed in the order they are declared while `doFrist` in reverse order.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I really wish it had been named "addFirst/Last" or "insertFirst/Last", then.